# Baby Girl Stretching

Tags: infant

I am a first time mother and I have a 4 month old baby girl. She stretches so severely and intermittently. Could this be normal? What could be the cause?

Comment: Everyone stretches. It feels good.

Comment: When you say _severely_, can you describe it in more detail? Is it extreme extension of all her limbs, is her head bent back? What is her facial expression? Does it tend to be just after waking up, or randomly (unconnected to eating/sleeping/pooping)?

Comment: Yeah, could you describe in more detail what exactly it is that she does?

Comment: Thanks mom, No odd facial expressions ,,head isn't bend nor temperature'' she does it most of the time she needs rapt attention or being angry when I lay her down',like she wants to get up herself and kinda struggling to suit herself"( lol)

Comment: This sounds like a concern you should discuss with your pediatrician. That said, both our daughters did what we called a "peanut stretch" (stretching so far they were bent backwards) and survived the experience.

Comment: @OloriAdeola - Thanks for adding some information, but there still isn't enough information here to understanding what;s happening. Why do you say "severe". Does she just stretch all four extremities, or does she wiggle around as well? Does she seem otherwise entirely normal? When did this start? How intermittent is "intermittently"? These are important points to shed light on. Add anything that might help.

Comment: Thanks every one" Her Paediatrician said today that she is Just and Absolutely Fine'',God bless Our Bundles of Joy!

Answer (score 2):

If there are no additional worrying behaviors (cries, painful expressions, arc-like bending instead of a straight stretch) I'd say it's normal, it's OK, it's even good, because muscles, apparently, are working as they should.

And it seems so "severe" because we are used to babies lying with their legs bent, curled - a baby stretched, with straight arms and legs, seems somehow unnatural. It isn't, though:)

Answer (score 0):

It is normal and a good growing sign. As long as your baby is active, happy and feel comfortable then no need to worry. Enjoy!! Baby is learning to use his muscles it seems.